# Gas wall oven vent

Tags: gas, vent, oven

I’m replacing a Roper gas wall oven with a new oven. The new ones don’t have vents. The existing vent runs up the cabinet and through the roof. I just had a new roof put on and I don’t want to pull the vent out.  How can I cap it from inside and leave it there?

Comment: Since it exists, I'd leave it open (perhaps screened) in the wall oven cavity space for passive venting.

Comment: The oven in our GE electric range has a 1.5 inch diameter vent under the small back burner. I assume this is to provide a low resistance path to equalize pressure in the oven as temp changes drastically. Is that what this vent is in the Roper wall oven? How can your new oven not have one? Or does your new oven have a vent that just connects to the inside space?